# How do I filter by relationship columns in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this query

```
public function index()
{
    $properties = PropertyDetail::query()->with('propLocation');

    $properties->where('type', Input::get('unitType'));
    $properties->where('purpose', Input::get('purpose'));
    $properties->where('active', 1);

    if (Input::has('specifyType')) {
        $properties->where('specify_type', Input::get('specifyType'));
    }

    if (Input::has('location')) {
        $properties->where('state', Input::get('location'));
    }

    $result = $properties->get();
    return View::make('portal.properties.view', compact('result'));
}
```

`propLocation` is my second table now how can I search the stats value there,
How this should be done?

I tried this:

```
if (Input::has('location')) {
    $properties->where('state', Input::get('location'));
}
```

but it does not work.

> Column not found

Comment: What column are you missing?

Comment: `state` it's in the second table `propLocation` witch I jointed   `->with('propLocation')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot filter relationship columns like that. You need to use `whereHas()`.

Try like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $properties = PropertyDetail::query()->with('propLocation');

    $properties->where('type', Input::get('unitType'));
    $properties->where('purpose', Input::get('purpose'));
    $properties->where('active', 1);

    if (Input::has('specifyType')) {
        $properties->where('specify_type', Input::get('specifyType'));
    }

    if (Input::has('location')) {
        $properties->whereHas('propLocation', function ($query) {
            $query->where('state', Input::get('location'));
        });
    }

    $result = $properties->get();
    return View::make('portal.properties.view', compact('result'));
}
```